# How to get a list of files of a huge size directory without using ls command (90GB)

Tags: linux, command-line, command-prompt

In linux server, is there a way to get the list of files in a directory
without using commands such as ls-la?

Our log directory size is too huge (almost 90GB) that
when we use ls -la command to get the list of files in that directory,
the command prompt does not come back...

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your files system - you may want to empty some space on the partition and try again. `ls` has no problems with large directories.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for [`unix.stackexchange.com`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

> echo *

... will show files in the current folder through file globbing on Bourne compatible shells.

This lists all files down one level:

> echo */*

In Bash, if globstar is set (set with *`shopt -s globstar`*, unset with `shopt -u globstar`), this will list all files recursively:

> echo **

For More info, you may visit [This Link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11023/linux-command-to-list-files-except-ls)

and your following problem why not you use a limit to list file?

this command may help you

> ls -U | head -4

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there are other commands, but you could combine `ls` with other command like:

```
ls -la | less
```

which still lists your files but you can move up and down (and search) easily. `less` does not load all the content (your 90GB) at once but it loads lines when you move around.

Or you can save output of `ls` to a file to open it later

```
ls -la > my_files.txt
```